# Oracle Graph two tier connection with Python does not work

Tags: python, oracle, graph

I'm trying to connect to my Oracle Cloud ADB with Python using two tier architecture:

> > > pgql_conn = pgql.get_connection("graphuser", "..", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@adb.eu-frankfurt-1.oraclecloud.com:1522:adw21c_medium?Wallet=C:\etc_ADW21\Wallet_ADW21.zip")

but there is a connection error:
 `.. File "c:\Python39\lib\site-packages\opg4py\pgql\_pgql.py", line 23, in get_connection conn = java_handler(DriverManager.getConnection, [jdbc_url, usr, pwd]) File "c:\Python39\lib\site-packages\opg4py\_utils\error_handling.py", line 38, in java_handler raise RuntimeError(message) from OriginalJavaException(exc) RuntimeError: I/O-Fehler: Invalid connection string format, a valid format is: "host:port:sid"`

and the host:port:sid format does not work.

How can I connect to my Oracle ADB Graph with Python two tier?

Thanks, Fried

Comment: Use the native Python driver API, python-oracledb, see [Connecting to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Databases](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-databases).

Comment: This Quick Start gives an overview: [Quick Start: Developing Python Applications for Oracle Autonomous Database](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/python/quickstartpython.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I'm afraid it's only possible through the Java connection as the PGQL graph statement needs to be translated to SQL.? Sorry, this two-level graphic is completely new to me.

Comment: Here the result trying with the PGQL statement:

pgql = """
                SELECT e.from_acct_id, e.to_acct_id, e.amount FROM
                MATCH (n:ACCOUNTS) - [e:TRANSFERS]-> (m:ACCOUNTS) on BANK_GRAPH_VIEW
                limit 10
            """
            cursor.execute(pgql)

=> OracleDB-Error: DPY-4010: a bind variable replacement value for placeholder ":ACCOUNTS" was not provided .

Comment: The solution for the Oracle ADB Graph service connecting is to use the AdbGraphClient API : [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/property-graph/23.1/spgdg/getting-started-client-tools.html?s=03&tab=Python#GUID-2D3FCCB7-1976-4C7D-ADEB-70F7F29C2CD2) 

`from opg4py.adb import AdbClient
config = {
 'tenancy_ocid': '<tenancy_OCID>',
 'database': '<DB_name>',
 'database_ocid': '<DB_OCID>',
 'username': 'ADBDEV',
 'password': '<password_for_ADBDEV>',
 'endpoint': 'https://<hostname-prefix>.adb.<region>.oraclecloudapps.com/'}
client = AdbClient(config) ` 

Thanks, Friedhold